# Альтернатива команде exec, для запуска скрипта

Tags: php

Для импорта большого каталога в интернет магазин написали скрипт, который импортирует файл. Скрипт работает примерно 2 часа, из-за объема данных.

Ранее мы скрипт запускали вручную из консоли, `php -f script.php`.

Сейчас возникла необходимость запускать этот скрипт по событию. Событие 'о появлении нового файла для импорта', которые является обычным http запросом.

Теперь каким-то образом, нужно из php скрипта (который получает http-запрос) запустить скрипт импорта - для выполнения в консольном режиме.

Сразу в голову пришло такое решение: `exec("php -f ...");`
Немного погуглил и понял, что это плохая идея. Которая может приводить к  разным ошибкам и не ожидаемым результатам.

Второе решение, о котором подумал, это система очередей.

1. Использовать готовые системы очередей, на подобии RabbitMQ, Kafka нет ресурсов. Т.к. Изучение этих систем займет много времени.
2. События о новом файле прилетают максимум 2-3 раза в сутки, не думаю что из-за этого стоит разворачивать столь серьезные системы.

Какие у вас есть предложения для решения задачи?

Может написать свою простую систему очередей, на основе таблицы в БД, + скрипт на кроне, который будет читать таблицу?

Или есть другие решения?

Comment: `crontab` спасет мир

Comment: `Изучение этих систем займет много времени.` зря вы так. записать в кролика и прочитать из него - дело не хитрое. но почти тоже самое можно и с записью в БД + крон, как вы уже сами и предложили.

Comment: @teran что имеется ввиду? Использовать таблицу + чтение по крону?

Comment: @Lexx918 можете показать пожалуйста простейшие примеры добавление в rabbitmq и чтения? 

И очень хотел бы понять принцип чтения из очереди. Правильно понимаю, что пишется скрипт, который слушает очередь, в этот скрипт выполняется постоянно? И этого добиться?

Comment: К сожалению пишу через новый аккаунт, т.к. на другом нет возможности писать(

Comment: не знаю зачем вам таблица. Есть файл - работаем, нет - выходим. Если интервал проверки меньше времени обработки, то переименовываем файл при начале работы.

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf примеры есть в официальной документации. они очень короткие и простые. самое сложное - написать живучего демона на пхп, но это уже другой вопрос. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html

Comment: @Lexx918 получается самому нужно писать демона, чтобы слушал очередь? кролик никаких штатных средств не дает?

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf самому. но можно просто кроном запускать скрипт и в нём проверять новые события в очереди. с демоном у вас будет почти мгновенная реакция на событие в очереди. с кроном раз в несколько минут-секунд (в зависимости от настройки расписания).